# How can I structure my data in swift IOS to use in tableView?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, data-structures, swiftui

I have a Data which am getting from API, its in a format

```
    [ 
     Appointments(startTime:"2022-09-01",subject:"Clinic Appointment",activityid:"2343"),
      Appointments(startTime:"2022-09-01",subject:"Night Appointment",activityid:"5738"),
      Appointments(startTime:"2022-09-01",subject:"Regular checkup",activityid:"2975"),
      Appointments(startTime:"2022-09-02",subject:"High Fever",activityid:"9274"),
      Appointments(startTime:"2022-09-02",subject:"Virtual checkup",activityid:"5648"),
      Appointments(startTime:"2022-09-03",subject:"Regular Appointment",activityid:"1892")
    ]
```

and I have an array where I have all the Dates of this month,
what I want is I want the data to be spread across my month with respect to date in the month
ex:

```
    [ 
       AppointmentsByDates(title:"2022-09-01" , appointments: [
            Appointments(startTime:"2022-09-01",subject:"Night Appointment",activityid:"5738"),
            Appointments(startTime:"2022-09-01",subject:"Regular checkup",activityid:"2975"),
            Appointments(startTime:"2022-09-02",subject:"High Fever",activityid:"9274"),
          ]),
       AppointmentsByDates(title:"2022-09-02" , appointments: [
            Appointments(startTime:"2022-09-02",subject:"High Fever",activityid:"9274"),
            Appointments(startTime:"2022-09-02",subject:"Virtual checkup",activityid:"5648"),
          ]),
       AppointmentsByDates(title:"2022-09-03" , appointments: [
            Appointments(startTime:"2022-09-03",subject:"Regular Appointment",activityid:"1892")
          ]),
       AppointmentsByDates(title:"2022-09-04" , appointments: []),
       AppointmentsByDates(title:"2022-09-05" , appointments: []),
       AppointmentsByDates(title:"2022-09-06" , appointments: []),
       .
       .
       .
       AppointmentsByDates(title:"2022-09-30" , appointments: []),
    ]
```

If you see in the above example startTime is what the Data is segregate with,

I did this in React Native using Maps and Reduce in Javascript, am new to iOS i need this structured data to populate tableview with multiple sections of every Date in a month.

[This image represents what I actually want in tableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1l3Oa.png)

Can you help me out with it?

Thanks,

Comment: You can create a dictionary with your unique startTime keys and then later add all the Appointments with that dictionary key as an Array. For ex - 
var mainDictionary:[String:[Appointments]] where the key is unique dates and Appointments are equal to date key. 

I hope I have not confused you here. Happy coding 

Answer (score 1):

Try this reduce method:

```
let sections = array.reduce(into: [AppointmentsByDates]()) { result, element in
    if let index = result.firstIndex(where: { resuty in
        return resuty.appointments.contains(where: {$0.startTime == element.startTime})
    }) {
        result[index].appointments.append(element)
    }else {
        result.append(AppointmentsByDates(title: element.startTime, appointments: [element]))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Timmy , had hard luck, your code is working all fine , there is some issue on my side, which is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, assume you have two struct which is Appointments and AppointmentsByDates

```swift
struct Appointments {
    var startTime : String
    var subject : String
    var activityid:  String
}

struct AppointmentsByDates {
    var title: String
    var appointments : [Appointments]
}
```

And you have your array just like above

```swift
let arr = [
    Appointments(startTime:"2022-09-01",subject:"Clinic Appointment",activityid:"2343"),
     Appointments(startTime:"2022-09-01",subject:"Night Appointment",activityid:"5738"),
     Appointments(startTime:"2022-09-01",subject:"Regular checkup",activityid:"2975"),
     Appointments(startTime:"2022-09-02",subject:"High Fever",activityid:"9274"),
     Appointments(startTime:"2022-09-02",subject:"Virtual checkup",activityid:"5648"),
     Appointments(startTime:"2022-09-03",subject:"Regular Appointment",activityid:"1892")
]
```

And for your question, It can divide into two task: you can map your array into dictionary which key is startTime and the value is list of Appointments which map which that key ; The keys here are the title of AppointmentsByDates

```swift
// make dictionary which key is starttime
var dict : [String:[Appointments]] = [:]
for value in arr {
    dict[value.startTime, default: []].append(value)
}

// make result mapping the key of dictionary to title
var result : [AppointmentsByDates] = []
for key in dict.keys {
    let value = AppointmentsByDates(title: key, appointments: dict[key]!)
    result.append(value)
}
```

And then you will have your result

```swift
print("result: ", result) // get your result here
```

Comment: When the data gets large, use a loop twice may cause performance issues

Comment: Dear @Timmy, that's the reason I use dictionary then after all I build list array with keys only. Like your solution, when the data gets large, firstIndex of which have O(n) complexity according to Apple docs, and you call each time append to result - It causes O(n^2)

Comment: Hi @bewithyou thanks for the solution , there is some issue in my code i guess, its not structuring the data, when I test your code is working for the example i gave